# PHP: Как избежать внутри класса создания экземпляров другого класса или, по крайней мере, сделать синтаксис лаконичнее?

Tags: php, классы, объекты, dom, xpath

Переписываю скрипт с процедурного стиля на объектно-ориентированный, но когда дело доходит до перевода спаршенного html в объекты, приходится работать с объектами классов библиотеки DomDocument. В результате получается работа с классом библиотеки внутри своего класса. Результат - громоздкий код, который получается даже хуже, чем в процедурном варианте.

```
class Parser
{
    public $url, $html, $dom, $xpath;
    
    function getInfFromTheSource () {

        $this->url = json_decode(file_get_contents('config.json', true));

        $this->html = file_get_contents($this->url->InfSource);

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($this->html);

        $xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли способ решить вопрос "красивее"? Не писать вот эти вот все нагромождения:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($this->html);
    
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
```

Вообще, у меня есть файл Parser.php и index.php. В index.php вызываются объекты класса Parser.php и других.. так и решается задача скрипта

Comment: А в чём проблема этих строчек? В ООП в одном классе часто применяется другой

Comment: хочется упростить, кажется тяжелее, чем в процедурном варианте, хотя начинал переписывать объектами, чтобы читаемость улучшить..

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, может, просто в объектно-ориентированном стиле не так решается задача обработки спаршенного html? Каким-нибудь автолоадером или конструктором.. Или используются другие методы, а не DomDocument

Comment: А что по-вашему значит "упростить"?

Comment: В ООП решается задача так же, как в не ООП - по написанному алгоритму)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Смотрел чужой код, но примера, близкого моей задаче не нашед..

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, может, можно как-то упростить... ? а я просто не понимаю, потому что не владею пока ООП...

Comment: Можно немного сделать код яснее, перенеся некоторые куски в другие методы, например, или ещё что-то. Т.к. этот код не следует принципу SOLID. А вот "упростить" тут нечего.

Comment: Понял, благодарю вас, попилю solid

Comment: Вы можете сделать `class Parser extens DomDocument { function getInfFromTheSource () { $this->url = json_decode(file_get_contents('config.json', true)); $this->loadHTMLFile($this->url->InfSource); }
}` код это уменьшит не сильно, но будет логичнее

Comment: Спасибо! Сам не додумался, приму это как вариант..